# Django disable csrf for admin

Tags: python-3.x, django

I need to disable csrf for all admin paths. If I try to import in urls.py

```py
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
```

and then

```py
urlpatterns += [path(admin_url, admin.site.urls)]
```

then when I go to admin I get an error

```py
TypeError at /core/admin/

'tuple' object is not callable
```

how to fix it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

In your admin.py file, import

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
```

Then add

```
@csrf_exempt
```

above the class.

Try that

Comment: I get this error when logging into the admin panel, even without the added classes in admin.py

Comment: your url in your path is wrong. Try using the default..
```
path('admin/', admin.site.urls, name='admin'),
```